# Limit Block format tags in WordPress wp_editor

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I'm working on a custom meta box and i am trying to limit the Block format tag to just P, H3 and H4 tags, i did it this way and not sure why it doesn't display the block format dropdown;

```
wp_editor( $content, 'fm_display_callback', array (
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'textarea_rows' => 5,
    'quicktags' => array( 
        'buttons' => 'strong,em,del,ul,ol,li,close' 
    ),
    'tinymce'       => array(
        'toolbar1'      => 'bold,italic,underline,bullist,numlist,alignleft,forecolor,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,undo,redo',
        'toolbar2'      => '',
        'toolbar3'      => '',
        'block_formats' => "Paragraph=p; Heading 3=h3; Heading 4=h4",
    ),
) );
```

as listed on [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE), it doesnt work for some reason. I have as well tried making the `block_formats` key into an array like this;

```
 'block_formats' => array(
      'Paragraph=p',
      'Heading 3=h3',
      'Heading 4=h4',
 )
```

and like this;

```
 'block_formats' => array(
      'Paragraph' => 'p',
      'Heading 3' => 'h3',
      'Heading 4' => 'h4',
 )
```

Not sure what i'm missing that is preventing the block format to display, as this is what i get visually (No dropdown)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `formatselect` in one of the toolbars, and WordPress by default have it in `toolbar1`:

```php
wp_editor( $content, 'fm_display_callback', array(
    ...
    'tinymce' => array(
        'toolbar1' => 'formatselect,bold,italic,...',
        ...
    ),
) );
```

Check [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L586) and https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/configure/content-formatting/#block_formats.

Comment: This took me three hours to find. Thank you Thank you!